# How to run PMD in bash

Tags: pmd

I'm currently trying to run PMD on git bash with the command "run.sh pmd -d -f -R" but I get an error saying 'Could not find or load main class net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD'. I've tried setting the classpath in the environment variable but still get the error. Does anyone know what the problem is ?

Comment: run.sh is populating the classpath (${scriptDir}/../lib/). Make sure that the lib directory is present, and contains all pmd jar files.

Comment: Okay, so I've checked run.sh. Where does the code get the value of ${dirname ${0}} ? is it one of the values I supply when running run.sh ?

Comment: I think I found it. It's just a dot. It then changes the directory to ./../lib, I checked the folder and all the jar files are inside it. I've set my classpath to "C:/pmd-bin-5.5.4/lib" and still get the error.

Comment: run your script as `bash -x ./yourScript.sh` and show your output (redacted as needed). Showing the contents of your script may help too. PMD works out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the PMD run.sh script. It supports the cygwin environment, but the git bash environment doesn't seem to be a vanilla cygwin environment (although all required cygwin commands are there).

The script builds up the classpath. Since it runs under a cygwin-like environment, the classpath looks like "/c/pmd-bin-5.5.4/lib/pmd-core-5.5.4.jar:...". However, the Java Runtime runs under Windows (and not cygwin), so the path needs to be translated into "C:\pmd-bin-5.5.4\lib\pmd-core-5.5.4.jar;...". Note, that the Windows notation of paths are used (the drive letter and semicolon as path separator).

The script uses the `uname` command, to determine, whether it runs under a cygwin-like environment. It only checks for "CYGWIN". But git bash uses e.g. "MINGW64_NT-10.0".

There is [the new issue #305](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/305) now, it should be fixed soon.

You can manually fix the script `bin/run.sh`, by changing the function `is_cygwin` to:

```
is_cygwin() {
    case "$(uname)" in
        CYGWIN*|MINGW*)  # look also for MINGW!!
            readonly cygwin=true
            ;;
    esac
    # OS specific support.  $var _must_ be set to either true or false.
    if [ -z ${cygwin} ] ; then
        readonly cygwin=false
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This works for the 64-bit version of git bash for it has a cygpath.exe available on its library. However, when running run.sh on a 32-bit git bash it returns an error 'cygpath: command not found'.

Comment: For me, it works even with the 32-bit git bash edition - cygpath is existing.
What does the command `uname` spit out? I've tested now plain 64-bit and 32-bit under 64-bit (WOW64) - since I've only a 64-bit windows at hand. For me it's now: "MINGW32_NT-10.0-WOW"

Running `cygpath` prints the help screen -> the command is found.

I've tested the latest git bash (2.12.1), could you please double check, you have installed the latest version from https://git-for-windows.github.io/ ?

Comment: Hi, it seems my git version is outdated (1.9.5), hence, the missing cygpath command. Printing `uname` gives me MINGW32_NT-6.1.

Comment: Git Bash is *not* Cygwin (despite stealing a few tools), it is MINGW which is not the same and not fully compatible. 

You can run git in Cygwin terminal, and there are tips online on how to replicate some of the custom prompts and completions from git bash in Cygwin. After doing this you really don't need both tools. After struggling to make git bash do more what Cygwin does, I did the above and haven't used git bash since -- Cygwin is now my git bash!